# Can't use outside components in storybook

Tags: reactjs, storybook, nextjs-storybook

I have a nextjs app with storybook setup but I have the components folder is located outside the nextjs project folder
[image]

When I try to import a component that uses a react hook I get this error in storybook "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')"
[image]

Here's a screenshot from the console
[image]